# How to start a new line with an indent

Tags: support, markdown

In my answer to the question [Does Israel have nuclear weapons?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/16178/does-israel-have-nuclear-weapons/16180#16180) I have a bullet with a quote inside it. I want to continue to write after the quote and in the bullet, so that the text will be indented. What is written is:

- During an interview to a German TV station in 2006 Ehud Olmert, the Israeli prime minister at the time said:

  > they are aspiring to have nuclear weapons, as America, France, Israel and Russia?
  >   This, however, is not a full official acknowledgment.

At the same interview Olmert said twice that Israel never claimed to have Nuclear Weapons, and on the next day said that there is no change in Israel's ambiguity policy, and that Israel will not be the first to introduce Nuclear weapons to the area.

The quote is properly indeted, How do I do the same with the paragraph that starts with "At the same..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the entire paragraph immediately after the quote to be indented, but not a quote?

If so, simply add a space immediately before the 'A' at the beginning of "At the same interview...".

Comment: Is it "1 space" or "same amount of spaces as needed to align the first character of the paragraph with the first character of text following the bullet point"? I always believed it to be the latter.

Comment: @DKV It is one space.  You can test it by opening the question in edit mode, adding the space, and watching the preview immediately indent the text.

Answer (score 3):

Like so:

```
* Bullet point

  > Indented quote

  Subsequent indented paragraph
```

… i.e. use one or more spaces at the beginning.